# Cant get fetched value in url tag

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get values from database in an anchor tag, but it's not working. My code is :

```
 <a href="{{url('admin/$getStudyLevel->slug_name/$getStudyLevel->id')}}" class="small-box- 
 footer">Get In <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: *but it's not working* - Please elaborate...

Comment: The url I am getting is : http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/$getStudyLevel-%3Eslug_name/$getStudyLevel-%3Eid

Comment: Well assuming the variable is correctly populated, have you tried concatenating the values to make a valid url? `{{ url('admin' . $getStudyLevel->slug_name . '/' . $getStudyLevel->id) }}`.

Comment: That is also happening because you are using `url` instead of `route`... So you end up with a horrible parameter

Comment: @BrianThompson Ity's working now, for to concatenate '/' . thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few way to pass param to url .Suppose consider you have following route

```
Route::any("user/{id}/{email}",[UserController::class,'index'])->name("userDetail");
```

then in your view using route name you can pass

```
<a href="{{route('userDetail', [$user->id,$user->email])}}">User Detail</a>
```

if you are using url then

```
<a href="{{url("user/{$user->id}/{$user->email}")}}">User Detail</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{url('user', [$user->id,$user->email])}}">User Detail</a>
```